# How to mask number on marker cluster in R leaflet

Tags: r, plot, shiny, leaflet, marker

```
output$countPlot <- renderLeaflet({
leaflet(cleanData) %>% 
     addTiles() %>% 
     addCircleMarkers(lng =~longitude+rnorm(1,0,0.0001), lat = ~latitude+rnorm(1, 0, 0.0001), clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(), label = ~id)})
```

My code now displays a leaflet map in R shiny with markers clustered and shows how many data points in each marker. I want to hide the numbers on the clustered markers but still show the color and size proportional to the data points in the cluster.

*Please find the map below:*

[image]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: The size isn't proportional to the number of points